# Download latest release from Artifactory with Gradle

Tags: gradle, ivy, artifactory

Artifactory has a feature of their API where you can download the latest release of a jar file (See http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact).

Their example is:
GET http://localhost:8080/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/[RELEASE]/acme-[RELEASE].jar

I'm working on a project where all builds get published and I want to grab the jar from the last one. So what I'm looking for is a dependency like this in gradle:

```
compile "org.acme:acme:1.0.0.9.[RELEASE]"
```

This fails due to escaping of the square brackets so I tried:

```
compile "org.acme:acme:1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D"
```

This seems to allow gradle/ivy to find the file but it fails because the .pom file version does not match what is defined.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':project:compile'.
> Could not resolve org.acme:acme:1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D.
  Required by:
      org.acme:acme:unspecified
   > Could not resolve org.acme:acme:1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D.
      > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: CachedResource: /Users/xxxx/.gradle/caches/artifacts-26/filestore/org.acme/acme/1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D/pom/3986d9c1a27873ce92c0dbd089fc1ca9618f8c1a/acme-1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D.pom for http://localhost/artifactory/org/acme/acme/1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D/acme-1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D.pom Errors: bad version: expected='1.0.0.9.%5BRELEASE%5D' found='1.0.0.9.80'
```

Is there any way to get gradle and ivy to pull the latest release from artifactory?

Comment: Please give some examples of the versions you want to match. The REST API and its conventions are irrelevant here. PS: Gradle no longer uses Ivy under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using the ivy syntax:

```
compile "org.acme:acme:1.0.0.9.+"
```

This solves the problem I have but I never did manage to get it working using the Artifactory [RELEASE] url.

Comment: You can't use the Artifactory REST API syntax in the Gradle dependency notation. `"org.acme:acme:latest.release"` might work though.